# sometimes impossible to load jquery masonry in internet explorer 9 et 8

Tags: internet-explorer, jquery-masonry

I have a problem in a site that I am trying to develop
Sometimes loading masonory is not properly despite the debug there is no error or appeal files or function calls
When I reload the page everything is fine sometimes and sometimes the calculation of positions is not
site :http://walter.testsstaging.com/site/
print screen of the problem : http://walter.testsstaging.com/masonory.png
thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's imagesLoaded plugin IE9 bug. Try modify your imageLoaded plugin code to [this](https://gist.github.com/1539102).

Comment: thank you very much
I already modified my code to not use ie picture loded

Comment: Thank you for this!  I don't know why the main branch of imageloaded doesn't have this change!